# Black screen on bootup

Tags: 14.04, grub2, nvidia, lightdm

I've had a problem since loading ubuntu alongside my windows install now. I'm running `14.04` and using `Gnome 3.12 shell` and `Lightdm`.

When booting up the Ubuntu splash screen looks normal and pushes me towards Lightdm as it should, upon entering Lightdm I feel like something is freezing or not loading as the graphical Lightdm doesn't start up, I hear the chime that Lightdm uses when it's fully loaded after afew seconds but the screen stays black - there's no cursor either. I can access all my `Ctrl + alt + f1` keys

My Nvidia drivers are the current drivers downloaded from Nvidia themselves which is `340.24`, I've tried purging that and going back to `noveau` or whatever the default driver is and had no luck at all. I'm using a asus GTX770

I've found a way to boot into ubuntu that works with everything set as I have it now and that is to boot into the `Linux Kernal 3.11-30 recovery mode generic` once the recovery menu has come up all I do is hit resume and it works first time and everytime. I have 3 kernal options `3.11-32, -30, and -24` -32 has errors sometimes and takes a while to boot, -30 works every time without fail and I haven't tested -24.

I have edited my Grub file to have `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nosplash nohz=off"` and it doesn't look like anything errors or freezes, it just goes through the normal boot up sequence, every line says OK at the end of it but then it still kicks me out to a blank `lightdm` screen.

I'm at work for the next 9 hours so I can't test anything but I'll update when I get back from work this evening.

Thanks.
`